# ¿Cómo realizar el cálculo de toLocaleString() en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema al realizar el cálculo de dos o más números que
estoy realizando con javascript. Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var a = 141232; // resultado "141,232" pero necesito que sea asi 141,232.00
var b = 2435; // resultado 24,235" de igual manera 24,235.00 <br>
var c = a.toLocaleString('en-US'); //convierto en símbolo monetario tambien usé toFixed(2)
var d = b.toLocaleString('en-US'); //convierto en símbolo monetario

var e = parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d);
console.log(e.toFixed(2));
```

Realizo la suma pero me da el resultado de esta manera = 165

Comment: El resultado que sale es 143.00 y no 165. Pero aparte de eso, parece que funciona bien todo. ¿Qué resultado esperas que salga? ¿Qué resultado obtienes? Deberías añadir una descripción mejor del problema porque no queda claro.

Comment: Hola Alvaro Montoro gracias por responder buenos lo que busco es que me sume los valores y en decimales si la suma es

Comment: Hola Alvaro Montoro gracias por responder, bueno lo que busco es que me sume los valores y que me de un resultado en algo como   de 12344 a 12,344.00                                                                                 
var a = 21510;
var b = 21740;
var c = a.toFixed(2);
var d = b.toFixed(2);
var e = Number.parseFloat(c) + Number.parseFloat(d);
console.log(e.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: "currency", currency: "USD"}));  me arroja un resultado como esta,  pero sin necesito sin el símbolo de dolar se puede ?

Comment: Entonces el problema es que esperas como resultado `143,657.00` pero te devuelve `143.00`, ¿es eso?

Answer (score 2):

**El problema** está en el `parseFloat` y en el hecho de utilizar `toLocaleString` justo antes. Como puedes leer en la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat):

> `parseFloat` convierte su argumento, una cadena, y devuelve un número de punto flotante. Si encuentra un carácter diferente al signo (+ o -), numerales (0-9), un punto decimal o un exponente, devuelve el valor hasta ese punto e ignora ese carácter y todos los correctos siguientes. Se permiten espacios anteriores y posteriores.

Entonces, al transformar el número con `toLocaleString`, estás haciendo que el separador de miles y millones sea una `,` que no es un carácter *permitido* en `parseFloat` y que hará que al parsear el número sólo se lea hasta la primera coma.

Es por eso que 141232 con `toLocalString` pasaría a ser 141,232 y al aplicarle `parseFloat` a esa cadena sólo se queda con la parte de delante de la coma: 141.

**La solución** sería procesar la cadena obtenida con `toLocaleString` para quitarle las comas, por ejemplo usando expresiones regulares. De ese modo te quedarán sólo los números y los puntos (si alguno) y la suma ya funcionará correctamente.

Para quitar las comas podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
cadena.replace(/,/g,"")
```

y al final te quedaría algo como esto:

```js
var a = "141232"; // resultado "141,232" pero necesito que sea asi 141,232.00
var b = 2435; // resultado 24,235" de igual manera 24,235.00 <br>
var c = a.toLocaleString('en-US'); //convierto en símbolo monetario tambien usé toFixed(2)
var d = b.toLocaleString('en-US'); //convierto en símbolo monetario

var e = parseFloat(c.replace(/,/g,"")) + parseFloat(d.replace(/,/g,""));

console.log(e.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: "currency", currency: "USD"}));
```

Comment: Si lo quieres sin el símbolo del dólar ($), puedes remplazar ese símbolo por la cadena vacía: `e.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: "currency", currency: "USD"}).replace("$", "");`

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro Montoro me salvaste thanks